# Expand div to contain absolutely positioned content

Tags: html, css, positioning

I have a `div` that contains a bunch of absolutely positioned controls.  These controls are dynamically generated and I want the `div` to expand so it will cover all the content in both width an height.  How can I do this in CSS?

Answer (score -4, accepted):

If i understand correctly you can write like this:

```
.parent{
 position:relative;
 width:100px;
 height:100px;
}
.dynamicDiv{
 position:absolute;
 top:0;
 bottom:0;
 left:0;
 right:0;
}
```

Comment: -1 This doesn't expand the parent to contain the children. It just sets the parent to a fixed size. It may have solved the OP's problem, but it doesn't answer the question.

Answer (score 10):

This is possible with [CSS grid](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Grid_Layout):

```
.container {
  display: grid;
}

.container > * {
  grid-area: 1/1;
}

.child {
  /* Instead of using top/left, use margins: */
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-left: 50px;
}
```

This creates a grid that only has one cell, and every child goes into that cell.

The layout of one child doesn't impact the others, they just overlay on top of one another, but the grid (`.container`) will expand to fit the bounds of all children.

Demo: https://codepen.io/jaffathecake/pen/zWrvZx

Comment: This does not answer the question.  Which was containing a bunch of absolutely positioned controls.  This solution would have them all stacked on top of each other.  There is no way to spread them out using this solution.

Comment: As I said in the answer, you can use margins to offset the items relative to the grid, eg https://codepen.io/jaffathecake/pen/qBPQoyL

Comment: this is incredible!

Answer (score 1):

That is difficult to achieve. When you have a relative parent with absolute children inside, they can not affect the size of the parent div.

You have to use relative children also. Why are the controls positioned absolute?

But where CSS fails, JavaScript comes to the rescue. So this can be solved.

Comment: In my case the children are absolutely positioned because I want to have a D3 SVG on top of a canvas where svg handles mouse interaction whereas canvas handles the actual rendering

Answer (score 0):

If you know the ratio of the container and the items scale with that ratio, you could use aspect-ratio to simulate the containment of the controls...

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/aspect-ratio

And here is a codepen where I use this approach:
https://codepen.io/cssguru/pen/yLoKYzR?editors=1100

```
<div class="img-swap">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/400x300/fff" />
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/400x300/fff" />
</div>
```

```
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 1rem;
}

.img-swap {
  position: relative;
  aspect-ratio: 4 / 3;
  background: red;
  
  $pos-x: 10%;
  $pos-y: 10%;
  
  img {
    position: absolute;
    border-radius: .25rem;
    box-shadow: 0 10px 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.1), 0 3px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.15);
    animation-duration: 14s;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
    animation-name: imgSwap;
    z-index: 1;
    bottom: $pos-y; 
    right: $pos-x;
    width: calc(100% - #{$pos-x});
  }
  
  img + img {
    animation-name: imgSwap;
    animation-delay: 7s;
    top: $pos-y; 
    left: $pos-x;
    z-index: 2;
  }
  
  @keyframes imgSwap {
    0% { opacity: 0; top: 0; left: 0; z-index: 1; }
    2% { opacity: 1; top: 0; left: 0; z-index: 1; }
    45% { opacity: 1; top: 0; left: 0; z-index: 1; }
    55% { opacity: 1; top: $pos-y; left: $pos-x; z-index: 2; }
    98% { opacity: 1; top: $pos-y; left: $pos-x; z-index: 2; }
    100% { opacity: 0; top: $pos-y; left: $pos-x; z-index: 2; }
  } 
  
}
```